# Writing Ionic Equation

Tags: ions

According to the rules of writing ionic equation, only compounds in aqueous state can be split or dissociated into their ions, whereas elements or compounds in solid, liquid or gas state remain as they are. But what about molten sodium chloride which is NaCl(l) in liquid state, isn't it dissociated into ions when melted? So can we split it into its respective ions when writing ionic equations?

Comment: Whose rules? Such a claim should have a specific reference and an explicit quote. I dislike a *reference to vague and unknown authority*.

Comment: @MaxW http://www.occc.edu/kmbailey/Chem1115Tutorials/Net_Ionic_Eqns.htm I got the information from here, perhaps I phrased it in a wrong way.

Comment: I think you mostly misunderstood. The webpage starts off with "*When aqueous solutions of sodium phosphate and calcium chloride are mixed together*..." So that is the context.

Comment: @MaxW so imagine when molten sodium chloride is one of the reactants which is NaCl (l) right? Can we separate it into its ions when writing the ionic equations? As 3rd point in the link said, "Bring down all compounds with (s), (l) or (g) unchanged."

Comment: How does molten sodium chloride have anything to do with the context of an aqueous solution of sodium phosphate and calcium chloride? You must be careful not to extrapolate statements beyond their context. // I'd agree that the webpage could use some editing. It is always nice to have several people read something to reduce the possibility of misconceptions in reading.

Comment: I mean molten sodium chloride in another chemical reaction, not referring to the one in the link. But seems like we don't use molten sodium chloride for chemical reactions. Please correct me...

Comment: Molten sodium chloride is definitely used for reactions, it just wasn't referenced within the context of the discussion on the webpage that you pointed to as the source of your confusion. If I'm reading a book on inorganic qualitative analysis and it says that "The $K_{sp}$ of silver sulfide is $6.31\times10^{−50}$." the context is an aqueous solution, and the statement doesn't imply anything about what happens with $\ce{Ag2S}$ in molten sodium chloride.

Answer (score 4):

The statement, "only compounds in aqueous state can be split or dissociated into their ions," is false in a number of ways.

1. As you state, molten salts *are* ionic, and there are room-temperature ionic liquids, such as [ethylammonium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethylammonium_nitrate) , $\ce{(C2H5)NH3+·NO3-}$.
2. In addition to water, there are other ionic solvents, such as [nitromethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitromethane), $\ce{CH3NO2}$. Salts in these solvents break up to form ions.
3. Further, not everything dissolved in water is ionized. Sugar (sucrose), for example, is *not* ionized.

Comment: http://www.occc.edu/kmbailey/Chem1115Tutorials/Net_Ionic_Eqns.htm I got the information from here.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased it in a misleading way. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Sodium and chlorine seperate into their ions. NaCl can turn into sodium ion and chlorine ion when molten. You could seperate it into respective ions if you want to write ionic equations.